# Сетевой интерфейс eth0 автоматически не включается после ребута

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, eth0

Поставил на `ubuntu 14.04` privateinternetaccess(PIA) с помощью скрипта install_ubuntu.sh ,было взято от [сюда](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ubuntu-openvpn) .
В network-managere появились `VPN` сервера, все хорошо. Всё работает без проблем. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настроил сетевой интерфейс `eth0` таким образом, чтобы автоматически подключался `VPN`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот проблема, после ребута системы он почему-то(сетевой интерфейс `eth0`) автоматичесчки не включается. Приходится включать вручную мышкой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могли бы вы сказать мне, что может быть источником проблемы?
Почему сетевой интерфейс `eth0` автоматически не подключается после старта системы?

Comment: проверте из терминала поднимается ли интерфейс, если да то глучный менеджер опять глучит.

Comment: update-rc.d networking defaults

Comment: Из терминала не поднимается. После команды sudo ifconfig eth0 up
 ничего не происходит.
Команда update-rc.d networking defaults выводит следующее:
update-rc.d: warning: default start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match networking Default-Start values (S)
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match networking Default-Stop values (0 6)
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/networking already exist.

Answer (score 1):

После некоторых манипуляций была та же проблема. Закоментировал строчку в /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

#Comment this line
#no-auto-default=my:ma:ca:dd:re:ss,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```