# Интерфейс eth0 не включается автоматически ubuntu 12.04. Настройка через консоль

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, консоль, configuration

При перезагрузке ОС

```
waiting for network configuration
waiting up to 60 seconds for network configuration
```

Устройство оказывается не запущенным.
Что бы поднять из консоли необходимо:

```
sudo ifconfig 192.168.1.210 eth0
```

Если запускать так:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0
```

то настройки IP4 не подгружаются

Мои действия:

```
sudo apt-get purge --yes network-manager
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.210
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 77.88.88.8
```

Тот же вопрос для [графической утилиты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577569/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-eth0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: попробуйте заменить директиву `auto eth0` на `allow-hotplug eth0`. по связанному вопросу: *nm* должен игнорировать интерфейсы, конфигурируемые «вручную», т.е. те, что упомянуты (в данном случае) в `/etc/network/interfaces*`.

Comment: Переустановил на всякий систему, в роутере поставил статик IP для мак адреса карточки, заработало.